# クレジットカードのトークナイゼーションはどのような仕組みですか？

Tags: untagged

- 乱数により生成した文字列を、元の文字列に戻すことが出来るのですか？
- 16桁のカード番号を全てトークン化した場合、16桁を全て保存するのですか？
  一部を保存して後で突き合わせるような方法とは異なる？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

下記サイトに詳しく掲載されているので、これを元に回答します。
[トークン決済とは？高セキュリティのクレジットカード決済方法](https://www.yamatofinancial.jp/learning/payment/what-is-token-creditcard-payment.html)

仕組みとしてはOAuthをイメージしてもらえばよく、クレジットカード情報をトークンとして実際の `カード番号` とは異なる16桁の `トークン` をトークナイゼーションサービス提供者（決済代行会社）が発行し第三者（加盟店）に渡し、加盟店はこれを利用して通常のクレジットカードであるかのように利用することが出来る、一方トークナイゼーションサービスの提供者は該当するトークンでの支払いがあり次第元々のカード番号を利用して実際のカード会社に与信を依頼するようです。

#### 乱数により生成した文字列を、元の文字列に戻すことが出来るのですか？

加盟店は戻すことができませんが、決済代行会社は戻すことが出来ます。

#### 16桁のカード番号を全てトークン化した場合、16桁を全て保存するのですか？

はい。

#### 一部を保存して後で突き合わせるような方法とは異なる？？

いいえ。

Comment: 「乱数により生成した文字列」を双方が保存しておき、後で突き合わせることで元に戻すということですか？　「乱数により生成した文字列」からだけでは「元の文字列」に戻すことは出来ない、という認識で合っていますか？

Comment: 乱数により生成した文字列（トークン）から復号化することは不可能であり、生成した側が元々の文字列を保持して突き合わせるということのようです。

Comment: なるほど。そういう仕組みなのですね。不可逆なものをどうやって戻すのか疑問に思っていたのですが、おかげで疑問が解決しました